# Why has AskUbuntu disappeared from the Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, status-completed

Browsing https://stackexchange.com/sites, I can't find [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and calling the SE API [sites route](http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites) does not return anything related to Ubuntu.
Do you know why?

Comment: I suspect this is all a result of an API problem.

Comment: @Rebecca you are probably right because Stackexchange sites is partially based on the SE API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gah, a bad setting got out there for Ask Ubuntu.  Took a while to get noticed due to caching.

API should report Ask Ubuntu just like everything else now.  Downstream sites (like StackExchange.com) will take a bit to catch up.

Comment: sorry for not having posted it on StackApps but I realized it was a SE Api topic just after @Rebecca comment.

Comment: We still love you @Kevin