# /tagsets/popular not working @StackExchange

Tags: status-completed, bug

After importing my tags from StackOverflow, I was directed to https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/1398/interesting-tags

Then I pressed "popular tag sets" and got an error at location https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/tagsets/popular

Don't have any additional info on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed now.  It was related to this bug: [Why has AskUbuntu disappeared from the Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73405/why-has-askubuntu-disappeared-from-the-stack-exchange-sites/73411#73411)